# How to get the email address of the windows logged in user using a java program?

Tags: java, windows

I need to get the email address of a user who has logged into his windows laptop in a corporate network. I need to get the email address using a java program.
Please suggest if there is any way available to get it directly or using native or third party library.

I googled a lot and nothing worked out

Comment: Ask for it when logging into the corporate network. Make it part of the login procedure.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? That may save someone answering with same information.

Comment: I tried using the methods available in jna.jar. I could get the user's active directory groups, firstname,lastname,username and domain. But not the email address.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize JNI to interface with native Windows APIs, create a native code implementation, and compile it into a shared library.
Then, load the library in your Java program and invoke the native method to retrieve the email address.

Comment: Which native Windows API do you mean?

Comment: You could use NetUserGetInfo.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo